# I've setup subdomains, but if users switch the subdomain to another user's account, it is insecure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I'm trying to setup subdomains for different accounts in my application per Ryan Bates' instructions:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised

Each user that registers creates an account, and when he logs into his account via his subdomain, he can type in another users subdomain and enter that user's account.

I can provide some code if it helps, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar app  you can look into it 
I am not using constraint on routes instead of manipulating via controller.
https://github.com/iparam/samay

Comment: This is very similar to what I'm doing.  I'm not using Devise though.  How is this working out for you?

Comment: Also, why did you choose this approach?  Did you experience the same problems I did with the subdomains?

Comment: I started building approach my own and i know i can use routes constraint but i might be not satisfied with it may be you can share some code so i can identified it.Is it working for u? i think any authentication system will work

Comment: It turns out my problem was that Rails stores a session for each authenticated user.  So as I'm testing in dev, I'm logging in to multiple accounts, using different subdomains and users.  I would then just type a different subdomain in the address bar while logged in to one of the accounts and was surprised that I was able to access some other account.  It turns out though, that I was also logged into this account too, and the session allowed me in.  I think this is not an insecurity.  I tested other sites that have subdomains, and they work the same way.